# Solving Shamir secret sharing schemes

Tags: secret-sharing

I have been working through the introduction to cryptography with coding theory book and have just come across Shamir secret sharing questions. However I just don't quite think I'm understanding it correctly. The question states:

**In a (2,19) Shamir threshold scheme working in modulo 41, there are two shares (2,14) and (4,25). Another share is (3,x) where x is unreadable. Find x, the polynomial and the message.**

I understand that I must solve for a line that interpolates (2,14) and (4,25) but haven't made it much further and have struggled to find questions in a similar structure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

To solve for the line you want, you really do the "basic" thing you might expect.
The formula for a line is $f(x) = ax + b$.
We know that $f(2) = 2a + b = 14$, and $f(4) = 4a + b = 25$.
It follows that $f(4) - f(2) = 2a = 11$, so $a = 11\times 2^{-1}\bmod 41$.
We have that $21\times 2\equiv 1\bmod 41$, so $ a = 11\times 21\bmod 41 = 26$.
You can then solve that $f(2) = 2\times 26 + b = 14\implies b \equiv 38$.
So $f(x) = 26x + 38$.

This argument works, but doesn't scale to higher-degree polynomials well.
To do this, it helps to know some linear algebra.
Specifically, the space of all polynomials of a given degree over a field $k$ $\mathcal{P}_n(k) = \{\sum_{i = 0}^n a_ix^i\mid a_i\in k\}$ forms a vector space over $k$.
This vector space is of dimension $n+1$.
One obvious basis for it is the monomial basis $\{1,x,\dots,x^{n+1}\}$.

For any set of $n+1$ points $x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}\in k$, there is a special matrix called the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Using_linear_maps).
It maps polynomials (written in the monomial basis) to the "evaluation basis", i.e. sends a polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i = (a_0,\dots,a_n)$ (in the monomial basis) to an "evaluation representation" $(p(x_0),\dots,p(x_{n+1}))$.
Anyway, the *general* way to reconstruct Shamir's secret sharing is

1. collect enough evaluation points $(p(x_0),\dots,p(x_{n+1}))$
2. use the (inverse) vandermonde matrix to change basis to the monomial basis $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$
3. evaluate $p(0)$.

There are optimizations you can do to this (you don't need to compute a full matrix-vector product, as you only need a single entry $p(0) = a_0$ from the result, so it suffices to compute an inner product), but the above is what I find most conceptually clear.

Comment: Thanks Mark you've made that much clearer to me now. I appreciate it!